# Set the default value in dropdownlist using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I have many options in my dropdownlist like:

```html
<option value="1">it's me</option>
```

I need to select the option who have value *it's me* inside the tag, not by attribute like `1`.

How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: Well i want to select them through the 'it'sme' value. but very few of us try to do with it.but thanks to all !

Comment: $("#myCombobox option[text='it\'s me']").attr("selected","selected");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292615/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Try this one..

Answer (score 109, accepted):

if your wanting to use jQuery for this, try the following code.

```
$('select option[value="1"]').attr("selected",true);
```

Updated:

Following a comment from Vivek, correctly pointed out steven spielberg wanted to select the option via its Text value.

Here below is the updated code.

```
$('select option:contains("it\'s me")').prop('selected',true);
```

You need to use the [`:contains(text)`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find via the containing text.

Also jQuery [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) offeres better support for Internet Explorer when getting and setting attributes.

[A working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halfcube/XyTtu/)

Comment: selected="selected" is also valid, and is what is suggested on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp).  +1

Comment: `$('select').val('something')` all that is required.

Comment: @halfcube-according to the question steven spielberg wants to select those options which text is 'it's me' not value

Comment: you are breaking the code dude check $('select option[text="it's me"]')

Comment: @vivek he wrote i need to select the option  not options

Answer (score 47):

You can just do this:

```
$('#myCombobox').val(1)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to do this from the Chrome Console, but it works in the JavaScript file.

Comment: Still the best answer in 2022.

Answer (score 7):

val() should handle both cases

```
  <option value="1">it's me</option>      


$('select').val('1'); // selects "it's me"

$('select').val("it's me"); // also selects "it's me"
```

Comment: This answer is copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description and does not answer what Steven is asking.

Comment: Mark, $('select').val('Two'); will solve the problem.. what else Steven has asked?

Comment: Not sure I can think of a situation you'd want to set all selects to a particular value? :-) Except '0', maybe...

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#userZipFiles option').prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to get the default options of a selectbox

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#dropdownList option[text='it\'s me']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: The single quote in *it's me* needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("select#cboDays option[value='Wednesday']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine:

```
$('#country').val($("#country option:contains('It\'s Me')").val());
```

Comment: Won't the use of double quotes inside double quotes create problems?

Answer (score 0):

One line of jQuery does it all!

```
$("#myCombobox option[text='it\'s me']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: Won't you have problems with the quotes within quotes?  How will JQuery know what's going on if your inner double quotes are not escaped?  Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: @jmort253 - if you are consistent you can mix single and double quotes as long as you use one to mark the outer string and the other to use internally in the string. Eg. "This is valid ''' :) " and "This is invalid """ :(".