# Set default value in dropdown of html

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I'm trying to set the default value of dropdown but I'm failing in to do so. Please tell me what is wrong with this code.

```
<span>Section Name:</span><select id="editSection" name="classSection" >
<option >A</option><option >B</option><option >C</option><option >D</option>
</select><br>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
$('input[id=editSection]').val($.trim(sec));
```

im trying to set sec as default value of dropdown. sec is a variable which is got after number of operations and whose value will be A,B,C,D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using the id. A `select` and `input` are not consider the same type of element.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4vmr/)

```
$('#editSection').val($.trim(sec));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#editSection").empty().append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>").append($.trim(sec));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below javascript code

```
var theText="B";

$("#editSection option").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == theText) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
  }                        
});
```

Option text is same as theText variable, the option will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good explanation on [Set the default value in dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781420/how-to-set-default-value-in-dropdownlist-using-jquery). It suggest use:

```
//for example let your sec variable be "C".
var sec = "C";
// it does the trick, and set default to sec's value.
$("select option:contains("+ $.trim( sec ) + ")").prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>Section Name:</span>

<select id="editSection" name="classSection" >
    <option >A</option>
    <option >B</option>
    <option >C</option>
    <option >D</option>
</select><br>


var sec = "C";
$('#editSection option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == sec){
        alert($(this).val());
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```