# Choose which select option is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have a select in HTML, which is dynamically generated.

When the page loads, I want to make the select box have a variable default option on page load, without having to change the order of the select list.

I cannot make this work by setting the `value` attribute when I dynamically generate the page. It is always the top value that is visible, regardless of the `value` property.

I would also like to be able to change this via jQuery after the document has been loaded.

Is this possible?

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" tabindex=1 id="instrument-select" 
                      name="instrument" value="<?php echo $instrument->slug; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($instrument_list as $instrument): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $instrument['slug']; ?>">
                              <?php echo $instrument["name"]; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: By default option, I mean the one that is initially visible to the user.

Comment: It is possible, can you add your code to the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781420/how-to-set-default-value-in-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to do this

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" tabindex=1 id="instrument-select" name="instrument">
    <?php foreach ($instrument_list as $instrument): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $instrument['slug']; ?>" <?php echo $instrument->slug==$instrument['slug']?'selected="selected"':''; ?>><?php echo $instrument["name"]; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

never add value attribute to **select** it should be there on every individual **option** and only need to make selected to required option.

Answer (score 1):

When you dynamically create the select html, add the 'selected' attribute to the option element you want selected;

```
<option value='firstOption'>firstOption</option>
<option value='someOption' selected>Some Option</option>  <!-- this one will be selected -->
<option value='thirdOption'>thirdOption</option>
```