# .prop() method does not work for selected option

Tags: jquery, prop

I encountered to very simple but amazing issue with jQuery. I decide ask question to figure out reason of it.

I have a `select` and two checkboxes like this:

```
Otion 1 is selected
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
Otion 2 is selected
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2">

<div>
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And JS like below:

```
$('#chk1').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        $('#select1 option:first').prop('selected',true);           
    else
        $('#select1 option:first').prop('selected',false);           
    alert($('#select1 option:first').prop('selected'));
});

$('#chk2').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        $('#select1 option:last').attr('selected',true);           
    else
        $('#select1 option:last').attr('selected',false);           
    alert($('#select1 option:last').attr('selected'));
});
```

`.prop` doesn't work but `attr` works properly. Why???

In couple of posts like below people said that we can use `.prop` for set `selected` but in my code does not work.

[Set the default value in dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781420/set-the-default-value-in-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

[**Online demo (Fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/ctmvtw1k/)

Comment: `prop()` in demo is working fine. What makes you say it doesn't work?

Comment: @charlietfl `prop()` doesn't add `selected="selected"` to `option 1` but `attr` does it.

Comment: Right....it's not supposed to. There is a difference between html attributes and dom node properties. Updating properties does not update the html attribute in the live source. Why does it matter if the attribute isn't changed?

Comment: @charlietfl I worked on form builder project like [this](https://formbuilder.online/) and I used jQuery plugin in that. I used `prop()` many times and it works properly but I need to change `selected` attribute in html to can check and set it in edit mode. I used `prop()` I thought I was wrong somewhere else. But finally I saw `prop()` didn't work.