# How to make an <option> selected when inserted with append?

Tags: jquery

I am adding a `<option>` with ajax and append it on success:

```
    success: function(data) {
      var newdata = data.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
      jQuery('#argomenti').append('<option value="">'+newdata+'</option>');
    }
```

But how would I make it so that it is the  selected as I will have many other  tags and values in that ?

Something like `$('#argomenti').val(newdata).prop('selected', true);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the default value in dropdownlist using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781420/set-the-default-value-in-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply set the 'selected' attribute, like this:

```
jQuery('#argomenti').append('<option value="" selected="selected">'+newdata+'</option>');
```

Comment: oh right i see, thought I had to set the value to the select too

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest:

```
// creating the element, passing an object of
// properties, and values, to set to that object:
$('<option>', {
  'selected': true,
  'text': newdata})
// appending the created element to its parent element:
.appendTo('#argomenti');
```