# setting a value of ASP:Dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, c#-2.0

I am trying to set a value for DDL say

```
$('#ddlState').val("State");  //State matched the name in DD list value
```

i have this line in ready function and it works for text boxes but not DDL.

I am also using labelify plugin for text boxes but when i set values like

```
$('#txtBox').val("Some Value"); //Which is not same as title value
```

the some  value is showing in the grey color.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters, .NET doesn't render the controls as

```
$('ddlState');
```

Try doing this:

```
$('#<% ddlState.ClientID %>').val('State');
```

Comment: when i did $('<% ddlState.ClientID %>').val('State');
i got exception """"CS1002: ; expected"""""

Comment: add the # in front of of, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:

[Adding options to a <select> using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: i am not trying to add an option but selecting some option from the existing list.

Comment: Try this one then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292615/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery