# How to restrict dropdown list change without disabling it

Tags: jquery

How can i restrict a dropdown list option change without disabling that dropdownlist.
Means i can not change the option and that dropdownlist should not be readonly.
My problem is my server is not reading disabled elements

Comment: What do you want to change? the values within it?

Comment: The more effort you put into your question, the better both the quality and quantity of the answers you'll receive. It's really very unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify the question. It's confusing what you're really asking. Maybe use some code to help explain.

Comment: Maybe you only want what this question answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292615/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Here's my bid](http://jsfiddle.net/m3v7y/)

**jQuery**

```
var lastSel = $('#foo').val();
$('#foo').change(function(){
    var $select = $(this), $status = $('#status');

    var $selOpt = $select.find('option:selected');
    if (!$selOpt.hasClass('disabled')){
        lastSel = $selOpt.index();
        $status.text('Selection changed to ' + $selOpt.val() + ' [' + lastSel + ']');
    }else{
        $selOpt.removeAttr('selected');
        $select.find('option:eq('+lastSel+')').attr('selected',true);
        $status.text('Invalid selection, reverting to ' + lastSel);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="foo">
    <option value="">Please select one</option>
    <option value="a">Option A</option>
    <option value="b">Option B</option>
    <option value="c" class="disabled">Option C</option>
    <option value="d">Option D</option>
    <option value="e">Option E</option>
    <option value="f" class="disabled">Option F</option>
    <option value="g">Option G</option>
    <option value="h">Option H</option>
    <option value="i" class="disabled">Option I</option>
</select>
<p id="status"></p>
```

---

### Plug-in Version

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        restrictedSelect: function(disabledClass){
            disabledClass = disabledClass || 'disabled';

            return this.each(function(i,e){
                var $s = $(e);

                // store the current selection. This is also used as a fall-back
                // value when the user selects something invalid.
                $s.data('currentSelection',$s.find('option:selected').index());

                $s.change(function(){
                    var $cs = $s.find('option:selected');
                    if ($cs.hasClass(disabledClass)){
                        $cs.removeAttr('selected');
                        $s.find('option:eq('+$s.data('currentSelection')+')').attr('selected',true);
                    }else{
                        $s.data('currentSelection',$cs.index());
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$('select').restrictedSelect('invalid-select-option');
```

Comment: Heh that's actually pretty cool, but why bother disabling it instead of just removing it from the menu? Why let the user select something only to tell them they weren't supposed to select it?

Comment: @AlienWebguy: You can do that, too. Just the same, you can set `.disabled { display: none; }`

Comment: Right, but then your jquery would serve no purpose :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#my_select').change(function(event){
    $(this).val(this.defaultSelected);
});
```

Comment: You can override that to whatever value you want. If the previous value is stored in a variable somewhere, simply provide it in `$(this).val( -- here -- )` Example: http://jsbin.com/ulufer/edit

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
//save the value selected when you load the page
var default = $('#yourselect option:selected').val();
//reset the value when the select change
$('#yourselect').change(function(event){
    $(this).val(default);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<select id="selectId" data-default="1">
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 ...
</select>

$('#selectId').change(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).data("default"));
});
```