# Readonly property not working

Tags: jquery

"readonly" property not working. Please check my code below 
http://jsfiddle.net/KZArL/

Even after setting readonly still i can change value...I am using the below code

```
$('select').prop('readonly','readonly');
```

If i disable post won't carry disabled value...

Comment: Don't you want `disabled`? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KZArL/1/)

Comment: Note that even for the HTML input field the name of the property is readOnly rather than readonly (which is the name of the attribute).

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, you cannot make a select read only, what you need to do is disable it:

```
$('select').prop('disabled', true);
```

Bare in mind that disabled form fields are **not** submitted with the form.

Comment: Though others mentioned disabled, +1 for mentioning it becomes invisible on form submission.

Comment: you could do `$('select').closest('form').submit(function(){ $('select').prop('disabled', false);});` to enable it before submit and have more or less the same than readonly

Comment: @enki No point as even if it's disabled it can be changed with simple tools.

Answer (score 3):

`<select>` doesn't have a readonly attribute, which is probably the issue you're seeing.

See the [MDN on `<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) for more details.

*On another question though, I just made a very simple [selection change prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846166/how-to-restrict-dropdown-list-change-without-disabling-it/6846368#6846368) plugin for jQuery if you're interested.*

Comment: @Enki: Indeed, but that makes it not show up on a form submission. Given it's a form element, I feel that wouldn't be desired.

Comment: well using value of a readonly is not good I think ( since we think user can't change it but the user can ) but if it's needed the field could be enabled before submit ( or the value copied in an hidden field )

Comment: @Enki: Or, `$('select>option:not([selected])').css('display','none');`

Answer (score 0):

You should use disabled:

```
 $('select').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('select').attr('readonly', true);
```

Comment: Anywhere from 4-7 minutes after it's been determined there is no readonly attribute you come up with this solution. Interesting.