# JQuery for setting a dropdown to default value when value of another dropdown changed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two dropdowns

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <label>User details</label>

<section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
             <div> @Html.DropDownList("Statuses", Model.Statuses(), "Select status", new { required = "required" }) </div>
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)       
        </section>  

        <section>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles)
             <div> @Html.DropDownList("AvailableRoles", Model.AvailableRoles(), "Select role", new { required = "required" }) </div>
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles)       
        </section> 

        <section>
            <div><button>Edit</button></div>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I want to write some JQuery to make the value of the status dropdown change to the default value when the value of the roles drop down is changed.  Any idea how this is done?

Thanks,

Sachin

EDIT:

The generated html is this:

```
<form method="post" action="/Admin/Account/EditUser?userName=user1">    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <label>User details</label>

        <section>
             <label for="UserName">User name</label>
             <div> <input type="text" value="user1" name="UserName" id="UserName" disabled="disabled"> </div>
             <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="UserName" class="field-validation-valid"></span>       
        </section>

        <section>
             <label for="Email">Email address</label>
             <div> <input type="text" value="sachinkainth@hotmail.com" required="required" name="Email" id="Email"> </div>
             <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Email" class="field-validation-valid"></span>       
        </section>

        <section>
             <label for="Status">Status</label>
             <div> <select required="required" name="Statuses" id="Statuses"><option value="">Select status</option>
<option value="Approved" selected="selected">Approved</option>
<option value="Registered">Registered</option>
<option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
</select> </div>
             <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Status" class="field-validation-valid"></span>       
        </section>  

        <section>
             <label for="Approved">Approved</label>
             <div> <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Approved" id="Approved" data-val-required="The Approved field is required." data-val="true" checked="checked"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="Approved"> </div>
             <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Approved" class="field-validation-valid"></span>       
        </section>

        <section>
             <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
             <div> <input type="text" value="e" required="required" name="FirstName" id="FirstName"> </div>
             <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" class="field-validation-valid"></span>       
        </section>

        <section>
             <label for="LastName">Last name</label>
             <div> <input type="text" value="e" required="required" name="LastName" id="LastName"> </div>
             <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="LastName" class="field-validation-valid"></span>       
        </section>

        <section>
             <label for="Roles">Roles</label>
             <div> <select required="required" name="AvailableRoles" id="AvailableRoles"><option value="">Select role</option>
<option value="Buyer" selected="selected">Buyer</option>
<option value="Seller">Seller</option>
</select> </div>
             <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Roles" class="field-validation-valid"></span>       
        </section> 

        <section>
            <div><button>Edit</button></div>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292615/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: @Samich: Not quite the same question now is it

Comment: Since you're writing JQuery (client side code) to solve your problem you should post the actual HTML markup that is generated, not the server side code used to generate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the change event...

```
$("#AvailableRoles").change(function(){
   $("#Statuses").val("New Value");
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JCZNy/)

Comment: Would `$(#AvailableRoles")` not be looking for an element with an id attribute of AvailableRoles instead of the name attribute?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: Those MVC Html helpers will set the ID and Name attributes to be the same

Comment: @Sachin: You did replace "New Value" with an approriate value right?

Comment: `@musefan: ` Ah, I see, I never realised that. Thanks for getting back.

Comment: @Sachin: I have added a link to a working example. If it doesn't work you have different issues.

Comment: Now, is there some way also of calling the Statuses() method from JQuery just before the status dropdown is set to the default value?

Comment: @Sachin: What is the `Statuses()` method? You can always add a function call in the change event before settings the value

Comment: The thing is that the Status method is in the model that I've passed in to this view.  Is it possible to call a model method from within JQuery?

Comment: @Sachin: No, this is not possible. Jquery is client side code. You best bet would be to make an ajax call to a new Controller Action that return a JSON result. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [here](http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-08-09/asp_net-mvc_3-json-result-jquery-ajax-form-validation) ... if you want more help on these subject I would suggest looking around and asking a **new** question on SO if you hit problems ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `change` event to do this.

```
$('select[name="AvailableRoles"]').change(function(){
   $('select[name="Statuses"]')[0].selectedIndex = 0;//Will select first option
});
```

I think the mvc helper method will render id attribute also which is same as the name field. In this case it is better if you use id selector.

```
$('#AvailableRoles').change(function(){
   $('#Statuses')[0].selectedIndex = 0;//Will select first option
});
```

Comment: @enigma - If the element renders id field then yes we can use id selector.

Comment: I've used this: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> but still it doesn't work

Comment: Can you put an alert inside the handler and see if the alert comes up?

Comment: As `Servy` said in the comment on the question, posting the rendered HTML of the dropdowns might help. Maybe there is something rendered which makes a difference.

Comment: @Sachin - Looking at the generated markup the default option is not "Select status". You want the default option "Approved" to be selected right?