# Selected Value in dropdownList using Jquery does not appear after set it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a problem with `asp:dropdownlist` when I try to change selected value to some thing using jquery after set the value, dropdownlist shows me last value and does not update to new selected value that have been set by me.

I try it(my html code)

```html
<select name="ctl00$cphMain$ddlBankList" id="ddlBankList">
 <option value="2">a</option>
 <option value="67">b</option>
 <option value="85">c</option>
 <option value="175">d</option>
 <option value="84">e</option>
    <option value="86">f</option>
</select>
```

and to modify html i use this js

```
$("#<%=ddlBankList.ClientID%> option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$("#<%=ddlBankList.ClientID%> option[value='67']").attr('selected', 'true');
```

But dropdownlist does not Jump to 67 value.

Comment: Try using prop $("#<%=ddlBankList.ClientID%> option[value='67']").attr('selected', true);

Comment: tax for your answer. when i call alert($("#<%=ddlBankList.ClientID%> option:selected").val()); shows that my value set to 67 but dropdownlist does not jump to value in UI

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the value of a DropDownList using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292615/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Comment: tnx Liam. to that post said dont forget to use .selectmenu('refresh') after set value but i get error when i use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

`$("#ddlBankList").val(67);`

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish1bhagat/hzc8udL3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery `val` function directly for select option in dropdown.

```
$("#<%=ddlBankList.ClientID%>").val('67');
```

Comment: tnx for your answer. when i call alert($("#<%=ddlBankList.ClientID%> option:selected").val()); shows that my value set to 67 but dropdownlist does not jump to value in UI