# How to Set a Dropdown Option Value by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, dropdown

```
<select id=workTypeSelection>
    <option id="-1">-Select a Work Type-</option>
    <option id="1">Common</option>
    <option id="3">Computer Maintenance</option>
    <option id="5">Facility Maintenance</option>
    <option id="19">Furniture Move</option>
    <option id="85">Global Work Type</option>
    <option id="24">Lease Request</option>
    <option id="21">Move Responsibility</option>
    <option id="20">Purchase Request</option>
    <option id="16">SLA Maintenance</option>
    <option id="60">Test 123</option>
    <option id="72">TEST J</option>
    <option id="73">test jj</option>
    <option id="65">TEST JOS</option>
</select>
```

How to Select "Test 123" as Currently selected option in The Dropdown list using jquery on page Ready using option id-> 60.

Comment: did you search it on google ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292615/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: tried many.. not working

Comment: @MithunS :  share the tried code

Comment: `$('select option[id="<your_value>"]').attr("selected",true)` try this. replace <your_value> from your id

Answer (score 4):

Try any from below,

```
$('select option[id="<your_value>"]').attr("selected",true)

$('#selectTagId option[id="<your_value>"]').attr("selected",true)

$('.selectTagClass option[id="<your_value>"]').attr("selected",true)
```

Comment: can I put a variable name in <your_value> field, and should it worked with having "<your_value>"  or i need to concate like this: $(.....["+variable+"]...)

Comment: If you a dynamic id then you need to do $("#selectTagId option[id="+your_id+"]")