# How to select a element from a menu down with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to select the element with the value `Sr.` from following code:

```html
<div _ngcontent-c16="" class="select">
  <select _ngcontent-c16="" class="select__menu" id="PRIMARYSuffix" name="PRIMARYSuffix" aria-describedby="PRIMARYSuffix_hint_0">
    <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="">None</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="sr">Sr.</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="jr">Jr.</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="ii">II</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="iii">III</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c16="" value="iv">IV</option>
  </select>
  <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="select__icon">
    <svg _ngcontent-c16="" focusable="false" role="img" data-di-res-id="de3487d6-5ddb0649" data-di-html-res="1">
      <use _ngcontent-c16="" xlink:href="#icon-chevron-down"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that _value_ is `sr`, not `Sr.` - different attributes.

Comment: I think this Question on Stackoverflow has your answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292615/how-can-i-set-the-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found the solution: `$('.select__menu').find('option').attr('value');`